# would memory be leaked if on allocation failed in this code?

Tags: c++, memory, smart-pointers, bad-alloc

so for my homework I am not allowed to use `std::smart_ptr` however I am allowed to implement it myself and make any changes I want

so this is what I did

```
#ifndef SMART_PTR_H_
#define SMART_PTR_H_

template<class T>
class smart_ptr {
    T* data;
public: typedef T element_type;
    explicit smart_ptr(T* ptr = NULL)
   : data(ptr) {}
    ~smart_ptr() {  delete data;    }
    T& operator*() const {  return *data; }
    smart_ptr& operator=(smart_ptr<T>&);
    };
template<class T>
smart_ptr<T>& smart_ptr<T>::operator=(smart_ptr<T>& ptr)
{
    delete this->data;
    T* new_data = new T(*ptr);
    this->data =new_data;
    return *this;
}
#endif
```

so my question is , for a code like this:

```
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList(const SortedList<T>& list):
  data(new smart_ptr<T>[list.max_size])
 ,size(list.size)
 ,max_size(list.max_size)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
        data[i]=list.data[i];// use of operator= of smart_ptr
     }
 }
```

so IF a `new` threw `std::bad_alloc`
would there be a memory allocation or would the destructor of `smart_ptr` take care of everything?

Comment: Why does your "sorted list" allocate a dynamic array of smart pointers?

Comment: `IF a new threw` Which of the two `new`s are you asking about?

Comment: @eerorika the `new` in the `operator=`

Comment: Also `operator=` should probably take a `const` reference

Comment: @MooingDuck you mean a memory leak inside the `operator=` function? and not in the loop?

Comment: @MooingDuck do you know how can I avoid this?

Comment: `std::smart_ptr` is not a thing... Assuming you mean `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: In addition to unary `operator*` you should define `operator->` so that your class really behaves as a smart pointer.

Comment: @prapin ok i will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so IF a new threw std::bad_alloc would there be a memory allocation

If `new` throws, then that `new` will not have allocated memory. However, it is possible for the constructor to have made their own allocations, and a poorly implemented constructor can leak those allocations if the constructor throws.

You have a much worse bug than a mere memory leak:

```
delete this->data;
T* new_data = new T(*ptr);
```

If `new` throws, then `this->data` will be left with an invalid pointer. Within the destructor, that invalid pointer will be deleted and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> which means that I should probably do the delete after the new ?

That would be much better, but it would still have potential for memory leak in case the destructor throws.

You should probably transfer the ownership of either smart pointer into a third, local smart pointer temporarily.

---

> but the thing is if the new throws what will happen to all the new that succeeded in the for loop?
>
> ```
> SortedList<T>::SortedList(const SortedList<T>& list):
>     data(new smart_ptr<T>[list.max_size])
> ```

The new[] array is owned by `SortedList::data`. If that is a smart pointer, then it should be taken care of within its destructor. If it is a bare pointer, then the pointed array as well as the smart pointers within the array will leak.

Note that since you allocated an array, the shown `smart_ptr::~smart_ptr` won't do the correct thing since it doesn't use `delete[]`.

> actually SortedList::~SortedList does delete [] data, would that be enough?

No. If the constructor of `SortedList` throws, then its destructor won't be called.

Comment: which means that I should probably do the `delete` after the `new` ?

Comment: but the thing is if the new throws what will happen to all the `new` that succeeded in the `for` loop? will the destructor take care of them?

Comment: @raghad: usually one would delete the old data, set your members to a "valid" (usually nullptr) state, and _then_ allocate the new data.

Comment: actually `SortedList::~SortedList` does delete [] data, would that be enough?

Comment: but If the constructor of `SortedList` throws, then we wouldn't have any data allocated , would we?

Comment: @raghad We would. The member initialiser of `SortedList::data` allocates.